# How to obtain a copy of just the files from an upstream repo?

Tags: mercurial

Upstream of me, in a repository I have zero control over and only http access to, there's a tag I want the files from.

How do I download just the files, without setting up a local repo and without downloading any changesets?  I only want a copy of the files as they are at a specific revision number (or named tag).

There are a lot of solutions to this involving `hg archive` but that has to be run from within the repository itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the upstream repo is available over hgweb/http and they have archives turned on there will be a URL like:

- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/archive/tip.tar.gz

which can take specific revisions or branch or tag names:

- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/archive/3cb1e95676ad.tar.gz
- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/archive/1.8.3.tar.gz

If they don't have that enabled then you have to clone the whole repo.